# Array not sorting based on compareto method override

Tags: java, sorting

I think I might be losing my mind because i cant for the life of me figure out why my Array is not sorting based on `x`.  Is there anyone who can take a quick look and let me know what I'm missing?

My goal is if I have an array of `(x,y)` pairs to sort the objects based on `x` from biggest to smallest.  The actual comparison might be off based on which object I need to subtract but at the moment sorting isn't happening at all.

I understand this is a well answered problem based on the numerous results that come up on google but I feel as though I have followed these answers and am not getting the result.

```
static class Point implements Comparable<Point> {
    long x, y;

    public Point(long x, long y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int compareTo(Point o) {
        if((this.x - o.x) > 0) return 1;
        else if ((this.x - o.x) < 0) return -1;
        return 0;
    }

    public long getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Below is the method I used to call `sort` and print the arrays. It's in the same parent class as `Point`:

```
static double minimalDistance(int[] x, int y[]) {
    double ans = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    Point[] pairs = new Point[x.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        pairs[i] = new Point(x[i], y[i]);
        System.out.println(x[i] + " " + y[i]);
    }
    Arrays.sort(pairs, Point::compareTo);
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        pairs[i] = new Point(x[i], y[i]);
        System.out.println(x[i] + " " + y[i]);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate `Arrays.sort(pairs, Point::compareTo);` what are you trying here ?

Comment: @Ravi the sort call should take my Points in array pairs and sort them based on my x value only.  So for example if i have (7,1) , (1,8), (2,7) the array should be (1,8) , (2,7), (7,1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sorting correctly. But you are sorting `pairs` array.

In the line below:

```
Arrays.sort(pairs, Point::compareTo);
System.out.println();
for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    pairs[i] = new Point(x[i], y[i]);     // <=== I mean this line
    System.out.println(x[i] + " " + y[i]);
}
```

You are overwriting `pairs` again. So it will look like it was not sorted.

If you want to update `x[]` and `y[]` arrays, do:

```
Arrays.sort(pairs, Point::compareTo); // Arrays.sort(pairs); would also work
System.out.println();
for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    x[i] = (int) pairs[i].x;                 // added this line
    y[i] = (int) pairs[i].y;                 // added this line
    System.out.println(x[i] + " " + y[i]);
}
```

**Working demo: http://tpcg.io/tYD924**

Comment: yep so i realized the array i was trying to verify was not the one i was printing out... ive been doing this to long today .. thank you